# Using SoftReference in ViewHolder pattern in android

Tags: android, tags, android-viewholder

I am new to this SoftReference and WeakReference stuff. I am making a generic `ViewHolder` pattern which keeps all views in `Hashtable` keyed by View's Id. I decided to use SoftReference for Hashtable and also SoftReference for value of item inside Hashtable.This is my **ViewHolder class**

```
public class ListItemTagHolder {
    private int index;
    private SoftReference<java.util.Hashtable<Integer,SoftReference<View>>> views=
            new SoftReference<java.util.Hashtable<Integer,SoftReference<View>>>(
                    new java.util.Hashtable<Integer,SoftReference<View>>());

    public ListItemTagHolder(int index){
        this.index=index;
    }

    public void destroy(){
        java.util.Hashtable<Integer,SoftReference<View>> vals=views.get();
        Enumeration<Integer> ks=vals.keys();
        while(ks.hasMoreElements()){
            vals.get(ks.nextElement()).clear();
        }
        vals.clear();
        views.get().clear();        
        views.clear();
        ks=null;
        vals=null;
    }

    public View getView(int id){
        return views.get().get(id).get();
    }

    public void addView(View v){
        views.get().put(v.getId(),new SoftReference<View>(v));
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index){
        this.index=index;
    }
}
```

I want to know the following

1. Is it correct usage of SoftReference ?
2. What will happen if my activity is destroyed and I am unable to
   call `destroy()` method of `ListItemTagHolder`. Will the memory get
   cleaned up for Hashtable ?
3. Will all the items in Hashtable be available to me everytime
   unless all reference to ListItemTagHolder are removed ?

Comment: does it really pay off to make such generic ViewHolder stuff? i assume you know what VH is for and how often it's used?

Comment: You shouldn't be using anything other than Strong References for the ViewHolder pattern. The ViewHolder pattern is designed to speed up the population of views in an adapter. By using some kind of weak references for the View Holder just slows everything down as they are more expensive compared to Strong Refs. Secondly your concern about the hash table being destroyed shouldn't be about the application lifecycle, but the runtime itself, Dalvik for instance. References other than Strong are at the mercy of the runtime, so you can't rely on them being in memory.

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 it's  not used for " population of views " but for accessing them, its a replacement for findViewById

Comment: Yes, and why do you use findViewById? To get a reference to a widget you want to do something with which generally is populating with your data :)

Comment: @pskink I know why ViewHolder is used. My app has around 10-12 different activities having ListViews. Each ListView has different type of data and layouts. That is why instead of creating 10-12 different ViewHolder or placing reference to all possible controls in one class I created this generic type of thing. Its helping me a lot.

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 thanks for the details. I will change it to Strong Reference and will also read more about these things. Thanks everyone

Comment: @RameezUsmani  i mean don't use holder pattern at all,  i didn't see any performance  boost when using it,  CursorAdapter doesn't use it and i wouldn't say it's  slow